# pointer not returning the value correctly

Tags: c++, pointers, reverse-engineering

I have a problem to return the value of the pointer in my program, the value of the pointer is not being saved, and when it reads it is returning null.

Header Code:

```
class PlayerHK : public Player {
public:
    PlayerHK();

    ULONG player_hp();
    ULONG player_power();
    ULONG player_hp2();
    ULONG player_power2();

private:

    struct CPlayer
    {
        BYTE padding[0x20];
        ULONG hp;
        ULONG power;
    };

    CPlayer *player;
};
```

Main Code:

```
PlayerHK::PlayerHK() {

        player = reinterpret_cast<CPlayer*>(*reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(0x00B1C4E5));

    }

    ULONG PlayerHK::player_hp() {
        return player->hp; //does not return the value
    }

    ULONG PlayerHK::player_power() {
        return player->power; //does not return the value
    }

    ULONG PlayerHK::player_hp2() {
        player = reinterpret_cast<CPlayer*>(*reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(0x00B1C4E5));
        return player->hp; //returns the value
    }

    ULONG PlayerHK::player_power2() {
        player = reinterpret_cast<CPlayer*>(*reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(0x00B1C4E5));
        return player->power; //returns the value
    }
```

when the program I run will read the PlayerHK, the value should not get saved? Did I forget to do something?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<CPlayer*>(*reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(0x00B1C4E5))` What do you think this does?

Comment: I commented on this question just a few minutes ago. Why did you delete it and ask it again?

Comment: @eerorika Obviously it non-portably reads the value at the address 0x00B1C4E5 and treats that as the address of a CPlayer structure.

Comment: 0x00B1C4E5 is the address to pick up the pointer.

Comment: Don't try to pick your own memory addresses unless you're programming an embedded OS and you have guarantees that what you want is really and truly at that address. `player = reinterpret_cast<CPlayer*>(*reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(0x00B1C4E5));` is a recipe for Le Grand Kaboom! on a modern  desktop OS.

Comment: @immibis I created it again because now the question would be another related to the pointer that does not save the value

Comment: @user4581301 I believe this code is loaded into another process and wants to read values from the main program (probably to cheat at a game). So the address of those values is known in advance by reverse engineering the game, but there is no other way to refer to them.

Comment: So when you construct the PlayerHK instance are you saying that `player` gets the value NULL?

Comment: Since the behavior of your code is undefined, you'll need to provide the exact compiler, compiler version, and compiler options you used for anyone to be able to even begin figuring out what's "wrong".

Comment: @immibis Good point. Carl, perhaps [`ReadProcessMemory` and friends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) are what you are after. Mucking in the internals of other processes is tricky stuff to get right, so expect more problems like this.

Comment: @user4581301 Not if the code is running in the same process already, which it obviously is since player_hp2 works. But Carl only gave that information in his previous question, not in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you are asking why

```
player = reinterpret_cast<CPlayer*>(*reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(0x00B1C4E5));
```

gives sets `player` to NULL when run in the constructor, but not when run in player_hp2 or player_power2.

The obvious answer would be that this memory location (0x00B1C4E5) holds the value NULL when you are constructing the object, and holds a different value when you're calling player_hp2 or player_power2. Perhaps the player hasn't been created yet when the constructor runs, so the pointer to the player (which you are reading) is NULL.